# Why isn't this fully evaluating

Tags: syntax, units

I'm still new to mathematica which sometimes feels magical to me. 
For example,

```
\[Epsilon] = Quantity[10, "Volts"]
R = Quantity[6.70, "Ohms"]
L = Quantity[5.50, "Henries"]
\[Tau] = L/(R)

i[t_] := \[Epsilon]/R (1 - Exp[-t/\[Tau]])
N[i[2]]
```

Which spits out

```
(1. - 1. 2.71828^Quantity[-2.43636, ("Ohms")/("Henries")]) (Quantity[1.49254, ("Volts")/("Ohms")])
```

Instead of fully evaluating that numerically, i.e. spitting out the above just evaluated into a single quantity with a unit, not a product of two quantities with unites.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Maybe this is what you want?: `i[t_] = UnitConvert[\[Epsilon]/R (1 - Exp[-t/\[Tau]])]
N[i[Quantity[2, "Seconds"]]]`

Comment: i agree with @RolfMertig you need to input time as a Quantity[2,"Seconds"] and not as a dimensionless value

Comment: also note if you use `UnitConvert[L/R]` in the tau def that will simplify to seconds at that point.